# Pandas groupby : using groupby to flag elements within their own groups

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

i am a beginner with py. My problem is that i failed to compare the elements of a time serie with their respective groups on a quantile measure.
Here is the DF :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#np.random.seed(444)

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo','foo','bar'],
     'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two','two', 'two', 'one', 'two','one','two'],
     '2018-09-28' : np.random.randn(10), 
     '2018-10-06' : np.random.randn(10),
     '2018-10-13' : np.random.randn(10)
})

df.index = ['se0','se1','se2','se3','se4','se5','se6','se7',"se8",'se9']
df.index.name = 'SE'
```

2 df are then created where the low and high limits are computed

#compute the low and high quantile according to the groups A and B and put
   it at the index level (se0,...)

```
df_low = df.groupby(['A','B']).transform(lambda x : x.quantile(0.45))
df_high = df.groupby(['A','B']).transform(lambda x : x.quantile(0.55))

print(df_low)
print(df_high)
```

#create a new df where there are flag (1 or -1) according to a test evaluating the value of se0,...,se9 versus their group quantile

```
f=lambda x : -1 if x<df_low else 1 if x>df_high else 0
transformed=df.iloc[:,2:].apply(f)
```

and there i have an error. Where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `x<df_low` returns a dataframe of booleans where you have True for the values in the original df that are larger than x.

That's why you get an error because the if statement expect a True or False, but gets a dataframe instead.

This should give you the dataframe you're looking for:

```
transformed = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.iloc[:,2:].index, columns=df.iloc[:,2:].columns)
transformed[df.iloc[:,2:] < df_low] = -1
transformed[df.iloc[:,2:] > df_high] = 1
```